# powershell inline fails in bamboo but passes from windows powershell CLI

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a command to copy files from bamboo to windows machine. I am using bamboos powershell interpreter for the same but it's failing with error:

> Failing task since return code of [powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass
>   -Command /bin/sh /usr/local/bamboo/agent1-home/temp/TAF-EL-JOB1-25-ScriptBuildTask-1469152609455458957.ps1]
>   was -1 while expected 0

Below are the two lines of code

```
net use \\10.103.200.45\LU1 Password123! /USER:administrator@vlab.local /PERSISTENT:NO | Out-Null

Copy-Item -Path pkfolder\* -Destination \\10.103.200.45\LU1 -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

However the same code getting executed in windows powershell CLI?

Comment: Why are you using `NET USE` instead of `New-PSDrive`?

Answer (score 2):

Your error message suggests that you're running this script on Linux.  Presumably you're using PowerShell Core 6.0?

`net use` in Windows is calling `net.exe`.  That's an external program, not a PowerShell command.  It does not have the same syntax as [the `net` command that's a part of Samba on Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/net).  That command on Linux is intended to have the same features as the `net.exe` command does on Windows, but it's primarily focused on `net.exe`'s features managing Windows NT domain controllers.

`New-PSDrive` is what I'd suggest trying first of all, but I'm not certain if that command has been completely ported to Linux yet.  PowerShell Core on Linux is just barely out of beta.

If that does not work then on Linux, you will probably want to use `mount.cifs`.

Comment: `New-PSDrive` [is implemented and working](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6) in v6.

Answer (score 1):

This should meet your needs:

```
$Null = New-PSDrive -Name Remote -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\10.103.200.45\LU1
Copy-Item -Path C:\Fully\qualified\path\to\pkfolder\* -Destination Remote:\ -PassThru -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: used $pass="Password123!"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('administrator@vlab.local',$pass)
New-PSDrive -name k -Root \\10.103.200.45\ELU1 -Credential $cred -PSProvider filesystem                                                                             
          No luck ,still getting same error.

Comment: Add `Exit 0` at the end.